# How to fix ‘/broadcasting/auth 401 (Unauthorized)’ error in Laravel 5.7 when using pusher

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, jwt, pusher

I am trying to set up pusher in my SPA. I've developed the App in  Laravel 5.7 and Vus js and am using jwt for authentication.

My Boostrap.js looks like this:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
encrypted: true,
auth: {
    headers: {
        Authorization: JWTtoken
      }
    }
});
```

`JWTtoken` the token am getting from JWT after I log in.

My BroadcastServiceProvider looks like this:

> I uncommented it in the config/app.php

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
     {
       Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth']);
       require base_path('routes/channels.php');
     }
}
```

My Channels.php file looks like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

I have also made sure that the entire application works with jwt as its only authentication method in the

> config/auth.php

My Event called UserEvent Looks like this:

```
class UserEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
       $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
       return 'themechanged';
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('App.User.'.$this->user->id);
    }
 }
```

Then in my vue component i have done this:

```
 Echo.private('App.User.1')
 .notification('themechanged', (data) => {
     console.log(data)
  })
```

but am getting this error in my console:
`broadcasting/auth 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: I think `JWTtoken` needs quotes, `"JWTtoken"`

Comment: When i add quotes to it, it becomes a string. i defined it as a constant which gets the bearer token that is created when i login.